# Safe use exec with php

Tags: php, exec, shell-exec

How can I use safe exec with php

I'm try to do command with exec like this :

```
exec("ejabberdctl register ". $_POST['username'] ." ". $_POST['password'])
```

In this command if any one use in password some thing like this

```
& free -m
&& free -m
;free -m
```

or

```
123456 & rm -rf /root
123456 ; rm -rf /root
```

..... etc

how can I block & and ; also if password --> (&&&&&&&&&&.....) or --> (;;;;;;;)

Any idea about safe use exec ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `escapeshellarg()`. It ensures that the value is interpreted as a single, plain shell argument. So it will not get executed even if you pass a command as argument.

```
$arg = $_POST['username'] ." ". $_POST['password'];
exec("ejabberdctl register ".escapeshellarg($arg));
```

Comment: And what if the password is like this : & free -m

Comment: && wont work if you use escapeshellarg(). So no problem.